# How do I format this properly?

Tags: c++, format

I am doing the "Random Walk" program, and I can't get the bars to display properly.

Here's my code (I will only include what I need help with) :

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    srand(time(0)); // make it "random"

    int max;
    int min;
    int location; //location of goat on bridge
    int steps;
    int total_steps;
    int choice;
    int move; // go forward or backward

    for (;;) {  // Keep running until user quits

        system("CLS");

        cout << "Random Walk Simulator" << endl;
        cout << "1) Display Trial " << endl;
        cout << "2) Run Statistics Over 50 Trials " << endl;
        cout << "3) Quit. " << endl;

        cin >> choice;  // get choice

        cout << "\n";

        if (choice == 1) {  // Display Trial

            steps = 1;
            location = 4;  // center of bridge

            cout << "Step 0: |   *   | " << endl;

            while (location >= 1 && location <= 7) {  // Keep running until goat falls off bridge

                move = rand() % 2 + 0;  // 0 and 1

                if (move == 0) {  // Move backward

                    location--;
                }

                if (move == 1) {  // Move forward

                    location++;
                }

                switch (location) {  // Show location

                case 0: cout << "Step " << steps << ": |       | " << endl;
                    break;
                case 1: cout << "Step " << steps << ": |*      | " << endl;
                    break;
                case 2: cout << "Step " << steps << ": | *     | " << endl;
                    break;
                case 3: cout << "Step " << steps << ": |  *    | " << endl;
                    break;
                case 4: cout << "Step " << steps << ": |   *   | " << endl;
                    break;
                case 5: cout << "Step " << steps << ": |    *  | " << endl;
                    break;
                case 6: cout << "Step " << steps << ": |     * | " << endl;
                    break;
                case 7: cout << "Step " << steps << ": |      *| " << endl;
                    break;
                case 8: cout << "Step " << steps << ": |       | " << endl;
                    break;
                default: break;

                }

                steps++;  // Iterate steps
            }

            cout << "\nTotal steps taken: " << (steps - 1) << endl; // (steps-1) since I start the goat off at the center of the bridge

            system("PAUSE");
        }
```

Here's a sample output:

```
Random Walk Simulator
1) Display Trial
2) Run Statistics over 50 Trials
3) Quit 
1

Step 0: |   *   |
Step 1: |    *  |
Step 2: |     * |
Step 3: |    *  |
Step 4: |   *   |
Step 5: |    *  |
Step 6: |   *   |
Step 7: |  *    |
Step 8: |   *   |
Step 9: |    *  |
Step 10: |   *   |
Step 11: |  *    |
Step 12: | *     |
Step 13: |*      |
Step 14: |       |
```

How do I format this properly? I'm kind of new to C++, sorry.

Comment: By proper formatting do you mean the line for step 10 should be aligned with step 9?

Comment: like this, for example: `cout << "Step " << setw(5) << steps << ": |..."`. Don't forget to add `#include <iomanip>`. Or you can add a `"\t"` before the `"|"`

Comment: _@Kawaiiii_ BTW: I'm pretty sure you'll get extra points for your solution, if you're going to replace the `switch()` statement with a generic loop (consider an extra function), that outputs `' '` and `'*'` character in right order and balance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place additional [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) to format your output properly.

Just replace

```
 << steps
```

with the following code

```
 << right << setw(2) << steps
```

in those `case` blocks

```
case 0: cout << "Step " << steps << ": |       | " << endl;
```

`setw(2)` sets the output field width to 2, while `right` tells to align the fields at the right border. Thus your output would look like

```
...
Step  8: |   *   |
Step  9: |    *  |
Step 10: |   *   |
Step 11: |  *    |
...
```

You'll need to `#include <iomanip>` additionally.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a tab.  At your lines that look like so:

```
cout << "Step " << steps << ": |       | " << endl;
```

Change it to be:

```
cout << "Step " << steps << ":\t|       | " << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `setw()`  [setw reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/)

So your `cout` should look something like

```
cout<<std::setw(9);
cout << "Step " << steps;
cout<<std::setw(0);
cout<<: "|      *|";
```